# get text value from dynamic created object

Tags: php, jquery

I'm still searching solution for getting values from  dynamic created object.

Follwing code generates dynamic object from zip2.php

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#submit").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      var q = $("#k").val();

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "zips.php",
          data: "q="+ q,
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(res) {
               $("#result").html(res); $('#result').trigger('create');  
        },
      });

    });       

});
```

```
<div data-role="content">

 <div id="result"></div>

</div>
```

It created object like this format.(contents of zips.php)

```
<? echo " <div><ul id='zips' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='c'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$out .= "
 <li>
 <a name='submit_button' href='#mainPage'><span class='zip1'>$zip1</span>-
 <span class='zip2'>$zip2</span><br />
 <span class='address'>$row[zp_sido] $row[zp_gugun] $row[zp_dong] $row[zp_bunji]   </span></a>
</li> \n";
}
  echo $out."</ul>";
```

?>

And this script get the text() value from dynamic object and insert it to form.

```
   <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a[name=submit_button]').click(function(){
                                         var inputVal1 = $('.zip1, this).text(); 
 var inputVal2 = $('.zip2', this).text(); 
 var inputVal3 = $('.address', this).text();


     $('div input[name=zip_code1]').val(inputVal1);  
$('div input[name=zip_code2]').val(inputVal2); 
$('div input[name=address1]').val(inputVal3); 

   </script>

   <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id='zip_code1' name="zip_code1" > - <input type="text" id='zip_code2 name="zip_code2"><br />
      <input type="text" id='address1' name="address1">
    </form
   </div>
```

The problem is that "var inputVal1 = $('.zip1, this).text();" gets null from dynamic objects class name "zip1".

Comment: Use `on()` with delegation instead of non-delegation shortcut `click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$('a[name=submit_button]').click(function(){..
```

use this:

```
$('#result').on('click', 'a[name=submit_button]', function(){..
```

As you `a[name=submit_button]` append to DOM after page load, dynamically via ajax request, so you need delegate event handler to that, ordinary event binding will not work here.

Read more about **[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on)**

---

#### Note

For general binding syntax of `.on()` is like:

```
$(target).on(eventName, handlerFunction)
```

but for delegate event systax is

```
$(container).on(eventName, target, handlerFunction)
```

Here `container` is the `Static-element` that belongs to DOM at page load and contains `target` and both `container` and `target` are valid jQuery selector.